# If you put something in the background does this mean it may also ignore interrpts?

Tags: terminal, background-process, signals

I know that you can kill the process by job ID or PID using PS or KIll.  but if its in the background using '&' will sending an interrupt signal will it also kill that process or Job?

Answer (score 1):

it the background just means the shell it not waiting for it to finish,
it can still still receive signals, (such as `SIGINT`), use the `kill` command to send signals.